# while insertind data using insert command it is not working

Tags: insert, command

```
insert into ra_bdr_msc_telco( Id , accessPointName , balance , bearerService , callForwardNumber , callPartnerExt , callType , calledIMSI , calledNumber , callingIMSI     , callingNumber , causeForRecordClosing , cellID , cfwIMSI , cfwNumber , chargeTotal , chargingID , chargingIndicator , dataVolumeDownlink , dataVolumeUplink , dayCode , defaultPriority , duration , endDate    , endTime  , fileId , filePos , forwardingReason , ggsnAddress , iMEI , incomingRoute , lac , localeID , mcc  , mediatedTime , mediationId , mmscSequenceNumber , mnc , msLocation , mscIdentity , netWorkElement , networkID , nodeID , originalCallPartner , outgoingRoute , prePostFlag , priorityLevel , productID , rated , recordSequenceNumber , reserved1 , reserved2 , reserved3 , reserved4 , reserved5 , reserved6 , roam , scpAddress , servedMSISDN  , serviceKey , serviceTypeID , smscReferenceNumber , sourceId , startDate , startTime , tariffSwitchInd , teleServiceCode , terminationType , timeZone , volume) values('111222333','NULL','NULL','','NULL','NULL','MO','NULL','96898785034222','413024100494697','776582419','NULL','Hitech City5,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','CallingParty','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','32','2012-02-02','13:41:50','b01298689.dat.old','NULL','NULL','NULL','354750040197530','HRAMBA4-BSC','20088','20088','NULL','11/25/14 10:10 PM','','NULL','14F320','NULL','00FF02','MSC','NULL','NULL','NULL','TMGW3H_IP','PREPAID','NULL','NULL','','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','b01298689','NULL','NULL','1994776582419','NULL','VOICE_IDD','NULL','5','2012-02-02','13:41:18','NULL','11','0','+5:30','NULL');
```

im trying to insert 69 values for 69 fields..after clicking on enter in the next line it is showing "'> "symbol

Answer (score 0):

You have unclosed quotes near "'Hitech City5,"